# Use doubleclick for publishers to serve different ads for desktop and mobile

Tags: google-adsense, mobile, google-dfp

I am using AdSense and my goal is to serve a different set of ads for mobile users compared to desktop users.   I'd like to it to work as illustrated in the image below where desktop users see an ad in the left sidebar and mobile users see an ad further down the page.

[image]

How do I achieve this without breaking AdSense policy that only allows 3 ad units per page? The targeting functionality in the DFP order section seems to have something to do with this, but unfortunately, I could not figure it out.

Comment: Use responsive ad units. You can choose what will be the size of it and where it will be placed.

Answer (score 1):

AdSense supports [responsive ad units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en).   These ad slots can change size and shape based on their position on the page and the size available to them. There is no need to include ads of different sizes in your page and choose which to show.   Use a single responsive unit that is always shown.